How to save civimail default parameters
I would like all our Civimail to have the following options, by default, when our users create a new mailing :

Visibility : "users and admin". Currently, the default is "public"


Forward answers : the box is unticked by default. I want it ticked by default



Is there a way to do this?

When a new mailing is created it is set to default to those values. There isn't an UI config where you can change those values to preset.
It's hard-coded in the PHP file, you can alter it using pre() hook.

Thanks a lot !
Are you refering to this part of the documentation ?
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pre/
In the short term, as a quick workaround, I guess we can edit the PHP you mention, specifically these 2 lines ?
'forward_replies' => FALSE,
'visibility' => 'Public Pages',
(I know such changes would disappear after a version upgrade)

Yes th change will disappear, pre hook when object id is empty you can over-ride the same fields, and easy to maintain as an extension/module/plugin
